# powershell: Copy files to subdirectories based on name

Tags: powershell

I want to implement a particular copy.
Example: I have a file with name adidas[other part of name].jpg.
I want to read the first two file's character and insert in subfolder as images/A/D.
Others examples:
If I have Reebok the files goes to images/R/E
If I have Brooks the files goes to images/B/R
There is another problem. If in the first two character are present any symbol (.&$%- and all others) I have to skip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Where-Object` clause to filter on files that have a name that always starts with (at least) two characters in the range of A-Z and skip all other files.

Something like this:

```
$sourcePath  = 'D:\Test'
$destination = 'D:\Test\images'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-z0-9]{2}' } | ForEach-Object {
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath (('{0}\{1}' -f $_.Name[0], $_.Name[1]).ToUpper())
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetPath -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory
    }
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath
    Add-Content -Path 'D:\copylog.log' -Value "File '$_.Fullname' copied to '$targetPath'"
}
```

Comment: WOW! This is OK but I need A-Z and numbers.
And If there is the possibility to implement a log would be perfect.

Comment: @Dan I have added numbers in the test and a simple method for logging. If you feel my answer solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark icon to the left. This helps other people with a similar question finding it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Dot is illigal charecter for dir name

```
param (
    $sourceFolder = "D:\tmp\001",
    $destFolder = "D:\tmp\002"
)
foreach($firstChar in "&$%".ToCharArray()){
    foreach($secondChar in "&$%".ToCharArray()){
        "some text" | Out-File ("$sourceFolder\{0}{1}sufix.txt" -f $firstChar, $secondChar)
    }    
}

Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder | %{
    $firstChar = $_.Name[0]
    $secondChar = $_.Name[1]
    $dir = (Join-Path (Join-Path $destFolder -ChildPath $_.Name[0]) -ChildPath $_.Name[1]) 
    New-Item $dir -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Copy-Item $_ $dir
}
```

Comment: If I insert the script in D:\tmp\001 is OK but it creates folders like $ % and then create inside files like $$sufix.txt with the content "some text".
Then in D:\tmp\002 I find also new folders with names % $ and other symbols.